# vue.js build error: skip processing .env variables

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, webpack, vuejs2, html-webpack-plugin

There's public/index.html template that is processed by vue-cli-service and placed into dist/index.html.

We want to inject some environment variables dynamically into dist/index.html in kubernetes (after the build, e.g. we build, then deploy dist folder to different pods, and kubernetes injects different values into index.html dynamically in every pod). We use ${FRONTED_WHATEVER} syntax for that.

The issue is: build does not work if ${FRONTED_WHATEVER} syntax presents in the index.html. Webpack, htmlwebpackplugin or whatever tries to replace ${..} by itself and throws `ReferenceError: FRONTEND_WHATEVER is not defined`.

I found the documentation about injecting .env variables into .html files in webpack using <%=..%> syntax, but there's nothing about ${..} syntax. And, what's more important, there's nothing about how to skip/escape this processing. I tried to use  `\${}`, `$\{..}` and `\$\{..\}` but it does not work or gives the correct result.

The easiest way to reproduce the issue is: generate new default vue2 + webpack project, then add these lines into the head of public/index.html:

```
<script>
  window.FRONTEND_WHATEVER = "${FRONTEND_WHATEVER}";
</script>
```

The goal is to get build/index.html file with exactly the same lines.

Comment: Try to add `VUE_` prefix, for your env variables, for ex. `VUE_FRONTEND_WHATEVER` and then   use this syntax `<%= VUE_FRONTEND_WHATEVER %>`

Comment: It's `VUE_APP` prefix, and the question is not about using .env variables in the template. It's about how to NOT USE it, how to keep string like `${VUE_APP_WHATEVER}` untouched during build.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes
1. fill .env like that: `VUE_APP_FRONTEND_CDN=\${VUE_APP_FRONTEND_CDN}`.
2. add <script> into public.html with window.globalJSConfig = { VUE_APP_FRONTEND_CDN: "${VUE_APP_FRONTEND_CDN}" }.
3. Add build post processing script that works on dist folder and replaced ${VUE_APP_*} with window.globalJSConfig.*